# Building a new object using linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have an object from the db as follows:

```
Var oldobject = context.db.getValues()// Do db operations and get values.
```

I have a to build new List from ***oldobject*** ,and each ***newobject*** object has four properties  as :

```
Public class newClass
{
  Public int id {get;set;}
  Public string description {get;set;}
  Public string variation {get;set;}
  Public string size {get;set;}
}
```

All these information is present in oldobject but in a different format like:
***Oldobject*** contains 2 objects:

```
Oldobject
   [0] 
      Type      null
     >Menu->
                      Name                   “sample” 
                      -> Layouts            count =4
                           ->[0]
                               Size                                 “1”
                              ->One more collection   count=4
                                  ->[0]     
                                      ->Id                      1
                                          Variation         “Variance”
                                           Description     “Test”
   [1]                       

     I am expecting the newobject contains all the iterated data from the oldobject where,
```

**“Size”** is a common field for the **“One more collection”** object , so my
**`List<newClass> list`** has

```
{
Size:1
Id:1
Variation:”Variance”
Description: “Test”   
},
{
Size:1
Id:2
Variation:”Variance2”
Description: “Test2”
}
```

…so on and on.

Every Data is dynamic and “**Layouts**” may contain count  as 100 items also, and ***OldObject*** can also contain 100 items as well.
How do I extract this information without using forloop or is it alright to loop object by object in terms of performance?

Comment: You need to use a "Join" statement to query database and get bcack a single table from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
List<newClass> result = oldObject.Menu.Layouts
    .SelectMany(l => l.OneOrMoreCollection
        .Select(c => new newClass
        {
            id = c.Id,
            variation = c.Variation,
            description = c.Description,
            size = l.Size
        }))
        .ToList();
```